# Can you playback MP3s / Audio files on Bixby?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I'm interested in creating a Capsule for Bixby which will play audio files upon invocation - similar to the narrative news / flash briefing functions on Google Home & Alexa & their respective richMedia responses & AudioPlayer directives.

Is this possible with Bixby right now? The documentation does not mention an audio player & after googling, all I can find re: audio is that You can use Bixby to play audio from Spotify.

Has anyone built a capsule that plays dev supplied mp3/wav audio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at the moment but the ability to play mp3 files will be coming shortly. Stay tuned!

Comment: Thanks for the update -- that said, is there somewhere I can see a comparison of what Bixby's APIs *can* do vs. Google Asst & Alexa?